# How to extract certain data from list of serial port data using python

Tags: python

i am beginner. i have connected my arduino to my raspberry pi and get data from serial monitor. Below is the code that i used.

```
import serial
import numpy as np

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0,1]
while True:
    b = ser.readline()[:-5]
    str_rn = b.decode()
    string = str_rn.rstrip()
    print(string)
```

The ouput on each line consist of: **mac address,data,time**. How can i get just data (-83, -85, -89) from specific mac address (let say 40:49:0f) and pass into a variable in array? Can anyone assists? Thanks for help.

The output at the moment like this:

```
40:49:0f,-83,1412
56:ab:27,-87,1416
f4:c5:6f,-80,1417
40:49:0f,-85,1417
56:ab:27,-88,1417
56:ab:27,-86,1417
0f:b9:b6,-48,1417
40:49:0f,-89,1721
```

Comment: Are you asking how to `.split()` each line over the `','` character?

Comment: yeah after ',' , i just want to save that data after selection of certain mac address of interest...